# Can't Get Excel to Print a Specific Worksheet Using VBA

Tags: vba, excel, printing, excel-2010

Let's say that I have a workbook with 3 worksheets, "Sheet 1", "Sheet 2", and "Sheet 3". Now I want to print only "Sheet 1" so in VBA I used

```
Sheets("Sheet 1").PrintOut
```

But the macro still print all 3 worksheets. What happened that cause it to print all 3 sheets when I specifically write the code to only print 1?

```
Activesheet.Printout 'also print all worksheets.
```

I'm using: Microsoft Excel Professional Plus 2010

Comment: What version of Excel?

Comment: Hope this is what you're looking for: Microsoft Excel Professional Plus 2010, 14.0.7128.5000

Comment: Check out [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838253%28v=office.15%29.aspx) because your syntax looks correct.  Maybe you have some sort of funky print range that is set to print all 3 sheets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this and let me know if it works for you.

```
Sub PrintTest()
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    For Each sh In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If sh.Name = "Sheet1" Then
            sh.PrintOut Preview:=False, ActivePrinter:="NameOfPrinter", PrintToFile:=True, PrToFileName:=PSFileName
        End If
    Next sh
End Sub
```

Comment: "Try this" is usually more of a comment than an answer.

Comment: Interesting, and how do you suggest I include code in a comment?

Comment: In this case, the loop and variable are unnecessary.  However, the suggestion of using the definitions of optional items on `PrintOut` might hold weight.  You could write a comment with backticks ` that shows the code to try.

Comment: Yes, it works great for me and I appreciate your help. Sorry for taking a long time to reply.